# Record a squared resolution video in android

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview, mediarecorder

I am trying to record a video in square mode like instagram and vine does.

So far I have already experimented with Camera and MediaRecorder class and also tried various methods like setting preview size or video size.But I am not able to achieve the result.

What approach I should use to achieve the squared resolution video ?

I can say that following approaches can help me

1. Record a video and then crop it in square resolution (Is there any lib available for cropping ?)
2. Or Recording itself should be in square resolution.

Please guide me or suggest some new approach or trick.

Comment: I would imagine that `ffmpeg` can crop, though I have not researched the point. Vine definitely uses camera preview frames, as they said so in a conference presentation. Presumably, they crop those frames as they convert them into the video.

Comment: @CommonsWare So Ideally what I should do is Capture frames , store it somewhere and then using ffmpeg I should convert them in video. ffmpeg can convert images into video right ?

Comment: AFAIK, `ffmpeg` can assemble still images into video. I have not done so personally, and I do not recall Vine indicating what they used for that particular piece of the puzzle.

Comment: For API 18+, you can capture to a `SurfaceTexture` and then render that to a `MediaCodec` encoder with GLES, applying whatever transform you want.

Comment: @HardikTrivedi : I have to do almost same functionality as you mention, so can you please guide me....what you finally done?

Comment: @HardikTrivedi Do you get any solution ?

Comment: @Herry Unfortunately No :(

Comment: @HardikTrivedi 
Do you get any solution?